# Wordpress.org UI: How do you make Bulleted/Numbered Lists indent by default?

Tags: block-editor

When I am editing my Wordpress Post, it shows that my bulleted/numbered lists are indented. However, upon checking my website with the Preview button or via the live URL, it shows that my bulleted/numbered lists are not indented at all. In the below image, they should be indented inwards a bit below each Title. Like this:

- Example bullet that is indented below the previous paragraph.

[image]

How do I make all bulleted/numbered lists indented universally across my entire site? Thanks!

---

Edit: It is still not working after adding `li {list-style-position: inside !important;}` in the Appearance -> Additional CSS section. After using "Inspect", I see this block here. I don't think `li, ol, ul` should be in this block since this block seems to pertain to the text alignment and not the list alignment. Is there a way to remove them from here?

[image]

In addition, looking at these, I think the `list-style: disc` is okay, since that should represent the round circle of a bullet list. However, the `text-align` and `list-style-position` probably has to be updated to `indent` or something?

[image]

Comment: What are you designing your site with? HTML5, PHP, CSS3, Boostrap, Wordpress? We need more details to be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I am using the Wordpress.org UI. I will include it in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using your own installation of Wordpress you have a greater ability to make changes.

If you open your post in the browser and right click on your bullet point (list item), and select **Inspect** you should be able to see the element, (in this case ol and also li) and see how they are being styled.

[image: example bullet points screenshot]

[image: clicking on inspect]

[image: seeing styling being done to elements]

You can also see what stylesheet is doing the styling. Chances are, the formatting is getting overridden by the theme or by a plugin. (in my case nothing is overriding and it is working)

Once you know what stylesheet is doing the styling you can go in and change it (dangerous) or play it safe and put **!important** in your style. To do that you could go into the **Dashboard**, then **Appearance**, then **Customize**, and finally **Additional CSS**. There you could add your desired styles for `ol`, `ul`, and `li`.

For example you may want
`li {margin-left: 16px !important;}`
By putting **!important** it should override anything else that is interfering.

[image]

Save your changes and reload your page to verify you have overridden any other styling.

Comment: Thank you, I tried adding `li {list-style-position: inside !important;}` but it is not working. Please see my edits in original post with pictures.

Comment: OK you can see how the other stylesheets are modifying the formatting. I am no expert on li styles but I would try overriding padding as it is getting set to '0'. try changing it to 16px or something and see if that changes it - if so, you can tweak it to what looks good.

Comment: A good source for formatting lists is: https://jenkov.com/tutorials/css/lists.html

Comment: Hmm almost! After playing around with different numbers for `px` in `Padding`, it seems to be just indenting **just** the text, and not **the bullet and the text together**

Comment: Good - progress. Try margin instead.

Comment: You're awesome! Solved. The answer is `li {margin-left: 25px;}`. Didn't even need the `!important` tag. I think it was conflicting with my Table of Contents CSS, which set the indent to be less than the paragraph indent, and actually is correct in doing so (looks ridiculous with the paragraph indentation). But the paragraph indentation definitely needs more than the Table of Contents indentation.

Comment: Glad you were able to get it resolved!